# Getting back cookies from the request in Flurl.Http v2.0.1

Tags: c#, flurl

When using Flurl.Http v1.2 we had the following code:

```
1. var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
2. var url = baseUrl.AppendPathSegment("api/auth/login");
3. var client = url.EnableCookies();
4. ((HttpClientHandler)client.HttpMessageHandler).CookieContainer = cookieJar;
5. var result = await client.PostJsonAsync(new { UserName = userName, Password = password });
6. var cookies = cookieJar.GetCookies(new Uri(baseUrl));
7. _cookie = cookies[0];
```

After upgrading to v2.0.1 line 4 no longer compiles because `client` is no longer an `IFlurlClient` it's now an `IFlurlRequest`, as per the release notes.

I noticed that `IFlurlRequest` has a `Client` property, so I changed line 4 to be:

```
4. ((HttpClientHandler)client.Client.HttpMessageHandler).CookieContainer = cookieJar;
```

That now compiles but fails at run-time with an InvalidOperationException:

> This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.

I'm assuming that's because of the aggressive reuse of the underlying HttpClient. I added a line between 3 and 4 to create a new FlurlClient each time to ensure the instance could not have started a request.

```
1. var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
2. var url = baseUrl.AppendPathSegment("api/auth/login");
3. var request = url.EnableCookies();
3.5 request.Client = new FlurlClient();
4. ((HttpClientHandler)request.Client.HttpMessageHandler).CookieContainer = cookieJar;
5. var result = client.PostJsonAsync(new { UserName = userName, Password = password }).Result;
6. var cookies = cookieJar.GetCookies(new Uri(baseUrl));
7. _cookie = cookies[0];
```

This now works again, but I'm not sure I'm doing this the correct way. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't need to manage `CookieContainer` explicitly; Flurl makes working with cookies a lot simpler.

Generally you want to reuse `HttpClient` instances as much as possible, and 2.0 does do this for you by default when you don't create `FlurlClient`s explicitly, but in the case of persisting cookies over multiple calls you're probably going to want to manage `FlurlClient` yourself, otherwise multiple threads could be reading/writing cookies on the same collection.

Still pretty easy. I think your whole example can be reduced to this:

```
using (var cli = new FlurlClient(baseUrl).EnableCookies()) {
    await cli.Request("api/auth/login").PostJsonAsync(new {
        UserName = userName,
        Password = password });
    _cookie = cli.Cookies.First().Value;
}
```

Comment: Worked great. I did have to change `cli.Cookies[0]` to `cli.Cookies.First().Value` because the `Cookies` collection is a dictionary. I could also have indexed into it using the name of the cookie but figured I'd go this other route in case the cookie name changed.